# File path reads correcly but doesn't create file or write to it

Tags: c, file

I have a switch statement, one of the case goes as follows:

```
printf(  "What is the name of the file you want to store data in? \n");
                scanf( " %19s" , write);
                writef(tamanho, write, &a);
```

The function it calls is:

```
void writef(int tamanho, char write[20], Array * a){
    char path[20] = {"C:\\PC\\"};
    write = strcat(path, write);
    write = strcat(write, ".txt");
    printf(" %19s \n", write);
    FILE * file1 = fopen("write", "w+");
    printf(write);
    if(file1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
            fprintf(file1, "HELLO FRIEND I HAVE ARRIVED");
            fprintf(file1, "Dimensao: %d \n", &tamanho);
            fprintf(file1, "Nome : %59s \n", a->array[i].nome);
            fprintf(file1, "Morada : %79s \n" ,a->array[i].morada);
            fprintf(file1,"Codigo Postal : %30s \n" , a->array[i].codigop);
            fprintf(file1, "Telefone : %20s \n",  a->array[i].telefone);
            fprintf(file1, "Data de nascimento : %10s \n",a->array[i].aniver);
            fprintf(file1, "Genero : %c \n", &a->array[i].sexo);
            fprintf(file1, "Profissao : %59s \n",a->array[i].prof);
            fprintf(file1, "Altura : %d \n",&a->array[i].altura);
            fprintf(file1, "Contribuinte : %d \n",&a->array[i].contribuinte);
    }
    printf("Dados guardados com sucesso \n");
    fclose(file1);
}
```

It should print the information about the data into a text file thats created for that purpose.
The write variable seems to be holding the path as it should, the code completes without issue, but when I go to check no .txt file is created, I feel like its something really dumb that I'm overlooking but I can't seem to find it. One thing that is bugging me is the second time I print the write variable to check if its all as it should it prints the right path with a bit of gibberish in front of it.

Comment: What is `printf(write);` printing?

Comment: @stark I wanted to check the problem wasn't with the write variable, so I wanted to see what it was storing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be this line

```
FILE * file1 = fopen("write", "w+");
```

I assume, it should read

```
FILE * file1 = fopen(write, "w+");
```

without the quotes around the *variable name*.

---

Another important point is the size of the `path` array. It is just 20 bytes large and `write` seems to be 20 bytes too. The text `C:\PC\<write>.txt` might become larger than 20 bytes, if the name given is large enough. This would result in a write beyond the array, and might explain the "gibberish" you see.

Comment: OKAY YEAH, that did it, I'm sorry I feel mentally challenged right now.